# nanogallery2 v0.9.2a (31 January 2017) bug with glass

Tags: nanogallery

I use nanogallery2 (v0.9.2a - 31 January 2017).
There seems to be a bug.
When you click (quickly) 5 or more times on the magnifying glass "+", it is impossible to retrieve the basic image using the magnifying glass "-".
Same when zooming on a smartphone screen...
Can you help me to fix this bug please?
Is this a bug in the version?
Help me please.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you click/tap quickly on the zoom in/out buttons, the lightbox interprets this as a double-tap.
Double-tap enables/disables zooming on the image. So the weird effect.

This issue is fixed in nanogallery2 <strike>v0.9.3</strike> v1.0.0

[EDIT]
Zooming is not working in v0.9.3 in case of self hosted images.